# "Can't start redis server" exception occurs when trying to run Spring Boot on my MacBook M1 (Sonoma 14.0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, redis, runtimeexception

When I try to run my Spring Boot app using IntelliJ IDE, everything builds properly and no warning and errors are show. Once the app starts running the following runtime exception occurs:

`Can't start redis server. Check logs for details. Redis process log:`

This is the line where the exception is thrown:

[image]

The funny thing is that `outputStringBuffer.toString()` returns empty string.

Now, I am running Redis via the Docker. Now to be sure that the Redis is indeed up and running and that there is no issue with the Docker, I added Redis as a database in IntelliJ IDE and when I execute the following command: `SET 'foo' 'bar'` the appropriate key/value data was added successfully.

[image]

I even tried to install and run Redis locally but nothing changed, I still received the same error as above.

I double checked that every possible configuration is OK and indeed it is. I can connect to Redis via IntelliJ and DBeaver but I cannot connect it from my Spring Boot appplication.

Comment: I have the same issue on the same MacOS.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to MacOS Sonoma (v14.x) I've had the same issue. Its a common problem which is reported [here](https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis/issues/135#issuecomment-1773899523)

Fix that worked for me is to use different and upgraded repo for Redis embedded server: `com.github.codemonstur:embedded-redis:1.0.0`

[Link to mvnrepostiory](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.codemonstur/embedded-redis/1.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the application.yml file to load your redis server's host, port and password?
For example:

```
Spring:
  redis:
    host: 192.168.150.123
    port: 6379
    password: abcdef
    database: 2
    timeout: 30000ms
    lettuce:
      pool:
        max-active: -1
        max-idle: 500
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped a lot! By adding this configuration the problem was resolved:

`
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    database: 2
    timeout: 30000ms
    lettuce:
      pool:
        max-active: -1
        max-idle: 500
`